# LESS mixins with multiple arguments

Tags: css, less, mixins

I have this little mixin set up:

```
.linear-gradient(@direction:top, @color1:#fff, @color2:#000) 
{
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(@direction, @color1, @color2);
}
```

Then, in my `main.less` I'm trying something like this:

```
a { .linear-gradient(top, #999, #666); }
```

That works fine, by say I want to do something like this:

```
a { .linear-gradient(top,     , #666); }
```

**Now, the first color should default to its default mixin color. How do I do this? Is this even possible**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Less isn't quite that clever. You can either be explicit:

```
.linear-gradient(top, #fff, #000);
```

or use a variable as an abstraction to pass in the defaults.

```
@colorVar1: #fff;

.linear-gradient(top, @colorVar1, #000);
```

Less doesn't know how to handle an empty space, and will treat is as invalid.

Comment: There's no way that I know of. The problem is that LESS doesn't know which type of value will suit which parameter, so it has to assume that you'll provide them in order. You could try specifying the paramater variable name in the hopes that it'll use itself as a default (eg. `.linear-gradient(top, @color1, #000)`), but I haven't tried this. Might not work.

Comment: Nope, doesn't work. Hmm, so I ran into a limitation of Less I guess.

Comment: I *may* be mistaken, but I think it's actually a limitation of all preoprocessors. If you were using SASS you could use @if conditionals to handle the empty-string case, but you'd probably still have to specify to some level - eg `top,'',#000`

Answer (score 6):

You can also explicitly pass the arguments, where the remaining arguments assume their default values.

```
a { .linear-gradient(@direction:top, @color2:#666); }
```